# loopback race conditions while passing data between hooks

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to pass some data from beforeSave hook to afterSave hook via

```
  Model.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {

    if (ctx.currentInstance) {
       // some logic
       ctx.hookState.data = 'foo';
    }

    next();
  });

  Model.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
   if (ctx.hookState.data) {
     // use data
   }
   next();
  });
```

Do I have to worry about race condition? eg. before 'afterSave' runs, some another request overwrites ctx.hookState.data. Contexts are completely separated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctx.hookState.

> ctx.hookState is for sharing data between hooks (e.g. "before save"
>   and "after save").